# Отправка и получение массива через POST в .Net Web Api

Tags: c#, массивы, post, asp.net-web-api, controller

У меня возник вопрос каким образом передать в .Net Web Api массив с данными, чтоб получить его в контроллере веб апи и уже обработать как мне нужно. Кажется проблема заключается в том что я не знаю как должна выглядеть модель которая принимает массив (да и как его отослать я тоже не совсем понял) прикладываю ниже не много наглядной инфы по вопросу.

Модель в web api:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public string DataName { get; set; }
}
```

Модель в приложении в котором отправляю данные такая же.

Функция принятия данных в веб апи выглядит так:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Data))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostData(Data data)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Data.Add(data);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = data.Id }, data);
    }
```

Функция в приложении отправки данных выглядит так:

```
public string CreateData(string token)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string SomeName = TextBoxSomeCreateName.Text.ToString();
        var UserID = Request.GetUserId(token, SomeName);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        if (Passive1.Tag.ToString() == "1")
        {
            var savePassive1 = new
            {
                Id = 0,
                UserId = UserID,
                DataId = Request.GetDataId(Passive1.Content.ToString()),
                DataName = Passive1.Content.ToString(),
            };
            list.Add(savePassive1);
        }
        if (Passive2.Tag.ToString() == "1")
        {
            var savePassive2 = new
            {
                Id = 0,
                UserId = UserID,
                DataId = Request.GetDataId(Passive2.Content.ToString()),
                DataName = Passive2.Content.ToString(),
            };
            list.Add(savePassive2);
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/api/sendData", list[i]).Result;
            }

            return "";

        }
    }
```

Логика такая, что собираю данные через if в List (если таг равен 1 то считать информацию, если нет идти дальше), этот лист как я понял (массив с данными) нужно передать в веб апи единым целым (в примере, передает не массивом а каждый объект отдельно, что крайне затрудняет потом обработку в контроллере веб апи, нужно каждый объект обработать сравнить и т.п, это тонна кода).

Помогите пожалуйста понять (желательно на моем примере) каким образом правильно собрать данные в List и отправить единым целым в контроллер web api где я смогу хотя бы через тот же foreach вытащить все данные из лист и уже обработать (что то выкинуть, что то добавить в бд, вернуть ошибки и т.п)

Comment: Ну вы же хотите отправить коллекцию на API, так и меняйте тип принимаемых данных тут: `PostData(Data data)` на тот, что ожидаете, к примеру `Data[]` или `List<Data>`. В чем собственно у вас сейчас проблема я не пойму?

Comment: Так, а модели менять не нужно? какая должна быть строчка response в приложении которая отправляет лист? var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/api/sendData", list).Result; <- Такая?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, разобрался. Я так и знал что мой вопрос он плёвый, но меня просто заклинило :) что я хочу видеть чётко знаю и даже логику работы а вот реализация просто в ступор ввела, одним словом новичок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как подсказал EvgeniyZ в комментариях, нужно банально было в контроллере Web Api поменять`PostData(Data data)` на приём моего листа `PostData(List<Data> data)`. В итоге всё заработало как нужно, отправил из приложения собранный с данными List, `var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/api/sendData", list).Result;` в Web Api функиця его получила, я всё раскидал проверил как хотел через foreach, вернул все ошибки и т.п, **вопрос решен спасибо Stackoverflow без вас бы была еще одна бессонная ночь :)**